# Angularfire2 + Firestore query result with reference

Tags: angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I have few hundreds docs in a collection. And few of them are corrupted and I want to delete them. I know how to find the corrupted documents and I get them as a result of a query. But it's just a data, there is no document ID or anything.

So my question is, **how to delete documents which I receive in query?** Or is there another way how to delete documents based on some property?

```
getData(target) {
    return this.afs.collection('someCollection', ref => {
      let query: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
      query = query.where('label', '==', target);
      return query;
    });
  }

this.dataService.getData('CorruptedLabel').valueChanges().subscribe(resp => {
      console.log('resp', resp); // Here I get and array of objects
      // I would like to go through that array and call delete() on each item
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the firestore document reference and delete the doc

```
this.dataService.getData('CorruptedLabel').snapshotChanges().subscribe(snapshots
=> {
  snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
     if(snapshot){
          this.afs.collection('someCollection').doc(snapshot.payload.doc.id).delete();
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. But it doesn't do anything. Should I change something in the getData method please? The snapshotChanges part isn't fired.

Comment: if you getting correct value with `.valueChanges().subscribe()` that should be ok

Comment: With my original code I get an array with 4 objects, exactly as I should. With your code I get nothing. I've inserted console.log into the  map function and it isn't displayed. And I don't see any activity in the network tab. It's like it didn't do anything.

Comment: firestore must have an id along with any documents, may be you used `.valueChanges` to return data it didn't show up. with `.snapshotChanges()` from my answer you can do `.doc(snapshot.payload.doc.id).delete()`

Comment: Yeah, the id was missing, I've added it and I see you did too. Thank you very much, it works now.

Comment: Can you maybe explain more please? Why doesn't valueChanges have access to reference? Do you have a good source of documentation? I cannot find anything.

Comment: Check angularfire official [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#streaming-document-data), with [example](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges)

Comment: Thanks, I've read that documentation but it didn't help me much. I'll try again. Thank you, really.